# Symfony 2 api logout

Tags: android, api, symfony

I have an android application that uses a symfony based api. I have users that login through the phone, send requests to the server and then logout. The problem is that unless I delete the cookies in the android(which I am storing) the symfony server would not log out the user, despite the fact that the user goes to the logout route.

This is part of my security.yml file (And I have tried a lot of combinations with this file to no avail)

firewalls:

```
    api: 
        anonymous: ~ 

        provider: users 
        access_denied_url: /user/accessDenied
        pattern:    ^/api/user
        form_login:
            login_path: /api/user/login
            success_handler: Authentication_Handler
            failure_handler: Failure_Handler
            check_path: /api/user/login_check   
            remember_me: false

        logout:
           path:   /api/user/logoutuser
           success_handler: logout_handler
           target: /
```

I have also tried triggering controllers manually that call     $this->get('session')->invalidate(); and or that redirect to the logout path(some results around the web suggested that was a good idea, but it did not work) It just seems that, whenever cookies exist, the symfony server just logs the user in, that seems like a security issue to me considering that I am saving the cookies into shared preferences on android. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have located the problem. On logout the cookie headers are not sent, so the server has no idea whose session to invalidate. Making the android httpclient behave like a full fledged browser can be tricky...